# how to get date in increment/decrement order in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

IN my app i have label at middle position and its left & right position previous and next button occur. label shows current date. & whenever i clicked on next button its shows date incremented by one and vice-versa in case of previous button. how to achieve this......

Comment: Date incremented by one what?... (day, year, month, millisecond...)

Comment: Check this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889164/get-nsdate-today-yesterday-this-week-last-week-this-month-last-month-vari).

Comment: possible duplicate of [get NSDate today, yesterday, this Week, last Week, this Month, last Month... variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889164/get-nsdate-today-yesterday-this-week-last-week-this-month-last-month-vari)

Answer (score 0):

@sugita on the `IBAction` method of your previous button decrease the incremented date by 1 (i.e -1 for the incremented date),on every click of your previous button decrease the incremented date which u are giving to the label.It is like wise u r increasing it

Hope u understand!