# How I can get the NSDate of yesterday

Tags: ios, nsdate

how I can get the NSDate of yesterday in iOS?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889164/get-nsdate-today-yesterday-this-week-last-week-this-month-last-month-vari

Answer (score 15):

Here is one way to do that:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[components setDay:-1];

NSDate *yesterday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
```

Take a look at the [Date and Time programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html).

Comment: Doesn't subtract a negative number makes it adding 1 day?

Comment: The method dateByAddingComponents *adds*

Comment: I changed that variable name to just `components` instead of `componentsToSubtract` since we are actually *adding* here.