# How to get week startdate and week enddate from iphone calendar

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone.I am doing one project in that project i am struck in the concept of getting week startdate and week enddate of iphone calendar from my application.If anybody know this concept please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am position code. See it that will help you.

```
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];// you can use your format.
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];


    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

int dayofweek = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:today] weekday];// this will give you current day of week

    [components setDay:([components day]-(dayofweek))];// for beginning of the week.

   // or

   [components setDay:([components day]+(7-dayofweek))];// for end day of the week

    NSDate *beginningOfWeek = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat_first = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat_first setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString *dateString2 = [dateFormat stringFromDate:beginningOfWeek];
```

Hope, this will help you...

Comment: See my edited and and let me know if you find any difficulty...enjoy...:)

Comment: If it's help than you should accept the right answer . So other people(who might have same problem) can chose right answer and this way you can help yourself,stackover-flow,and other people...enjoy..:)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) fromDate:[[NSDate alloc] init]];

[components setHour:-[components hour]];
[components setMinute:-[components minute]];
[components setSecond:-[components second]];
NSDate *today = [cal dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:[[NSDate alloc] init] options:0]; //This variable should now be pointing at a date object that is the start of today (midnight);

[components setHour:-24];
[components setMinute:0];
[components setSecond:0];
NSDate *yesterday = [cal dateByAddingComponents:components toDate: today options:0];

components = [cal components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[[NSDate alloc] init]];

[components setDay:([components day] - ([components weekday] - 1))]; 
NSDate *thisWeek  = [cal dateFromComponents:components];

[components setDay:([components day] - 7)];
NSDate *lastWeek  = [cal dateFromComponents:components];

[components setDay:([components day] - ([components day] -1))]; 
NSDate *thisMonth = [cal dateFromComponents:components];

[components setMonth:([components month] - 1)]; 
NSDate *lastMonth = [cal dateFromComponents:components];

NSLog(@"today=%@",today);
NSLog(@"yesterday=%@",yesterday);
NSLog(@"thisWeek=%@",thisWeek);
NSLog(@"lastWeek=%@",lastWeek);
NSLog(@"thisMonth=%@",thisMonth);
NSLog(@"lastMonth=%@",lastMonth);
```

from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1889908/932011)

Comment: If you have this code accept this answer and increase your points.