# How to check whether a date belongs to this week or not in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

Hello I have a date string like this.`11/14/2016`. What I want to do is check it whether is it

Today or This week or This month. I can compare today and the month. But how can I check whether this date belongs to "This Week"

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: May be this will help:[http://stackoverflow.com/a/1889908/5575752](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1889908/5575752)

Answer (score 3):

Given two dates,

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *then = // some other date
```

Find out if they're in the same week with:

```
BOOL sameWeek = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] isDate:then equalToDate:now 
    toUnitGranularity:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear];
```

That line asks if they're "equal" with a granularity of a week, meaning that they're "equal" if they're in the same week.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
- (void)thisWeek:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *todaysComponents = [gregorian components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSUInteger todaysWeek = [todaysComponents weekOfYear];
    NSDateComponents *otherComponents = [gregorian components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear fromDate:date];
    NSUInteger datesWeek = [otherComponents weekOfYear];

    //NSLog(@"Date %@",date);
    if(todaysWeek==datesWeek){
        NSLog(@"Date is in this week");
    }else if(todaysWeek+1==datesWeek){
        NSLog(@"Date is in next week");
    }

}
```